# How to extract one row of a 2D string vector to vector of double?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stdvector, stdstring

I have a function to calculate moving average:

```
void MovingAverage(double inputSeries[]
                 , size_t inputSize, size_t window, float* output )
```

My train of thought to do my calculation:

1. construct a loop and extract one row of `vec2D` each time
2. use the `MovingAverage` function to get output

For the first step, the 2d-vector is parsed from a csv file:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec2D{
    {"S0001","01","02","03"}, {"S0002","11","12","13"}, {"S0003","21","22","23"}
};
```

I want to extract one row of this 2D vector (say the 2nd) and store the row as a 1d vector `std::vector<double> copyRow` then calculate the moving average for each row.

```
copyRow = {11,12,13}
```

I tried `vector<double> copyRow(vec2D[0].begin(), vec2D[0].end());` but it doesn't work because the 2D vector is `std::string` type.

I also tried for loops:

```
int rowN = vec2D.size();
int colN = vec2D[0].size();
double num;
for (int i = 0; i < rowN; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < colN; j++) 
    {
        num = stod(vec2D[i][j]);
        copyRow[i][j].push_back(num);
    }
}
```

But it appends all values from all rows into the vector. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: And since there are too many rows and for each row I have to do calculations, I don't want to use just one loop and specify the row index to do so

Comment: I edited my question thank you @JaMiT

Comment: *I want to extract one row of this 2D vector (say the 2nd) and store the row as a 1d vector* -- Sounds like you are giving us your solution, and trying to get your solution to work.  Maybe describe on a high-level, what problem are you trying to solve?  Maybe there are better ways to achieve whatever the goal it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Cyan *"for each row I have to do calculations,"* -- this would seem to be a reason to transform your 2D `string` data into 2D `double` data, rather than extract a single row of data. This leads me to think that maybe you should present a bit more context so we can better understand the constraints you are working under (and better understand your goal, as PaulMcKenzie suggested).

Comment: @JaMiT  Yes actually I want to calculate the moving average for each row. I edited my question

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes I want to calculate the moving average for each row. I edited my question

Comment: @Cyan Maybe you are using the wrong data structure / container for this.  If the first element is not a number but a string, a better alternative would seem to be `std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>>`.  Then you have your vector of doubles right there, mapped to the string id (the first element in your 2D array).  A 2D vector isn't contiguous anyway, so I don't see losing any performance by using a `std::map` instead.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie could you elaborate it?  Not sure if you mean `std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> copyRow(vec2D[0].begin(), vec2D[0].end());` This doesn't work because of errors. Many thanks

Comment: Forget about the 2D vector for a moment -- it seems to be the wrong tool for the job.  Assume you have your data in the map.  Then to get the vector of doubles is simply: `auto &vDouble = theMap[stringID];` -- No copying is done whatsoever.  In other words, it seems this entire issue is approaching [XY Problem territory](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You should also mention how that 2D vector becomes populated with data, because that method would have to change also.  If it's your creation (and not that you were forced to do this by some teacher or other entity), then ditch it and go with the map.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I edited my questions. This is my train of thought to get the output but it would be great if there are other easier ways

Comment: @Cyan [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2367f3d2707c39b7)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I saw it. It seems work, but my string is separated by ',' instead of space. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried `vector<double> copyRow(vec2D[0].begin(), vec2D[0].end());` but it doesn't work because the 2D vector is string type.

You can make use of the algorithm function [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) from `<algorithm>` to do this.

Since the first element of each row cannot be transformed to a `double` , you can skip it by starting from one element after begin iterator:

```
 #include <algorithm> // std::transform

std::vector<double> copyRow;
// reserve memory for unwanted real locations
copyRow.reserve(vec2D[1].size() - 1u);

std::transform(std::cbegin(vec2D[1]) + 1, std::cend(vec2D[1])
    , std::back_inserter(copyRow), [](const auto& ele) {
        return std::stod(ele);
    });
```

**([See a Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r4Gb1vEn1))**

Comment: Thank you but you can see from my edited question that the first element of each line cannot be transformed to a float number

Comment: Thank you it seems work, but in my code it shows `auto' not allowed in lambda parameter ` How can I fix this?

Comment: @Cyan Generic lambda (as shown in this answer) require c++14 or later. Yours might be still c++11. Try  [](const std:: string& ele) {
        return std::stod(ele);
    }); as lambda.

Answer (score 1):

After the comments in the main thread, it seems that the initial data structure (a 2D vector of strings), doesn't seem to be the best choice.

Instead, an associative container, such as a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` would seem to be more suited for the task you're trying to accomplish.  Basically, the key to the map is the non-numeric field, and the data would be the `vector<double>` associated with the key.

Then it just becomes a matter of getting a reference to the row of doubles, given the key value.

Here is an example of code that illustrates this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string test = "S0001,01,02,03,S0002,11,12,13,S0003,21,22,23";

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> mymap;
  int numCols = 4;
  int count = 0;

  std::istringstream strm(test);
  std::string data;
  std::string id;
  
  while(std::getline(strm, data, ','))
  {
      if ( count % numCols == 0)
          id = data;
      else              
         mymap[id].push_back(stod(data));
     ++count;
  }
  
  for (auto& m : mymap)
  {
      std::cout << "\n" <<  m.first << "\n";
      for (auto& v : m.second)
         std::cout << "  " << v << "\n";
  }
  
  // Get the vector associated with S0002
  std::cout << "\nHere is the data for S0002:" << "\n";
  std::vector<double>& vDouble = mymap["S0002"];
  for (auto& d : vDouble)
     std::cout << d << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
S0001
  1
  2
  3

S0002
  11
  12
  13

S0003
  21
  22
  23

Here is the data for S0002:
11 12 13
```

There are two main points:

1. The vector of strings no longer becomes an issue, since on the population of the `std::vector<double>` elements, the `std::stod` is called on the string to convert the string to a double.
2. Accessing the `std::vector<double>` becomes trivial -- all you need to do is get the key (the string data) and access (by reference in this example), the vector associated with the key.  No copying, no `std::transform` calls, or anything like that.